# Update form with foreign key Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a form that contains 3 data. One data is a data from another table that has been linked using a foreign key. What should I add so that the data in the table that has been saved can appear in the edit form and can update it?

**View**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
  <div class="form-group">
    <strong>Kelas:</strong>
    {!! Form::select('idkelas', $kelas_theresia, [], array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
  </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $kamar_theresia = Kamar_Theresia::find($id);
        $kelas_theresia = Kelas_Theresia::pluck('name','id')->all();
        return view('kamar_theresia.edit',compact('kamar_theresia','kelas_theresia'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Product  $product
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
         request()->validate([
            'nama' => 'required',
            'idkelas' => 'required',
            'ketersediaan' => 'required',
        ]);

        $input = $request->all();
        $kamar_theresia = Kamar_Theresia::find($id);
        $kamar_theresia->update($input);

        return redirect()->route('kamar_theresia.index')
                        ->with('success','Kamar Theresia updated successfully');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look for the documentation in the "Recursively Saving Models & Relationships" section:

```
  https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models
```

This is an example:

```
$client = Client::find($id);
$client->name = "Daniel";
$client->addressInfo->street = 'Daniel's street';
$client->push();
```

Regards